# SQL Server connection string works with isql, but not node-odbc

Tags: node.js, sql-server, linux, odbc

I'm moving some of my apps off of an Ubuntu server and into some Docker containers to be orchestrated elsewhere. The biggest hurdle is the ODBC connection. Here's my setup based on [Microsoft's instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16#debian18):

```
FROM node:16.15.1-buster

RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/10/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
RUN apt-get update
RUN ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql18
RUN apt-get install -y unixodbc unixodbc-dev
RUN apt-get install -y libgssapi-krb5-2

WORKDIR /app
RUN npm install odbc
```

After installing the driver with the above commands I can successfully connect using isql:

```
isql -v -k "DRIVER={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server};SERVER=myServerName\myInstanceName;DATABASE=myDatabase;UID=username;PWD=password;TrustServerCertificate=YES;"
```

But I cannot connect with the `node-odbc` package in node.

```
const odbc = require('odbc');
const connection = await odbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server};SERVER=myServerName\myInstanceName;DATABASE=myDatabase;UID=username;PWD=password;TrustServerCertificate=YES;');
```

The above code throws the following error.

```
[Error: [odbc] Error connecting to the database] {
  odbcErrors: [
    {
      state: 'HYT00',
      code: 0,
      message: '[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired'
    },
    {
      state: '08001',
      code: 11001,
      message: '[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: Error code 0x2AF9'
    },
    {
      state: '08001',
      code: 11001,
      message: '[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.'
    }
  ]
}
```

Any ideas? I'm not familiar enough to understand why it would work with isql and not node-odbc. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: In Javascript the backslash character is referred to as an _escape character_. i.e.: if you were to `console.log("myServerName\myInstanceName")` then on the console output you'd only see `myServerNamemyInstanceName`. Have you tried using two backslashes?

Comment: If I put two backslashes `myServerName\\myInstanceName` it crashes with a segmentation fault.

Comment: Downgrading to Node v14 works. Anyone know how to make it work in a version greater than 14?